# Dreamweaver with SQL Server 2000 database

Tags: sql-server-2000, dreamweaver

I'm using SQL Server 2000. How can I connect Dreamweaver asp.net to SQL Server 2000.

Please give give the coding

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for connection strings??

Check out [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for a large selection of how to access SQL Server from a variety of platforms.

You'll find the [SQL Server 200 connection strings here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server).